# What is the difference between "paragrafo" and "alineo"?

Tags: word-choice

While *paragrafo* is very similar to "paragraph" in English and "paragraphe" in French, some people say it is an error to use it for this and the word *alineo* should be preferred. What is the difference between them and when should they be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Paragrafo

A "paragrafo" is a section of the text which usually consists of more than one "alineo". So this is the first "alineo" of this "paragrafo" with the title "Paragrafo".

('Paragrafo' also has a meaning for legal texts. Second "alineo")

## Alineo

After an "alineo" you begin a new line, sometimes with indenting.

This is the second "alineo" of this "paragrafo" about "Alineo".

Answer (score 7):

According to PIV/vortaro.net:

- alineo: Peco de teksto, normale konsistanta el pluraj frazoj, komenciĝanta per nova linio k ofte distingita de aliaj alineoj per vertikala spaco, deŝovo de la unua linio ks/piece of text normally consisting of multiple sentences, beginning with a new line and often distinguished from other paragraphs with vertical space, indent of the first line, etc.
- paragrafo: Ĉiu el la sekcioj de ĉapitro, en jura aŭ didaktika teksto, ordinare montritaj de aparta signo (§ aŭ ¶) aŭ de cifero/Each of the sections of a chapter in legal or dictated text, ordinarily shown by a specific symbol or letter

So, it seems that *paragrafo* applies only to legal documents and the like, while *alineo* is more general.

Comment: From the PIV entry of *paragrafo*: “paragrafo povas enteni plurajn alineojn”. A *paragrafo* is a section of a text like a subchapter, while an *alineo* just is one block text that starts and ends with a new line. Basically, every time you press ‘enter’ you start a new *alineo*, but not necessarily a new *paragrafo*.